# UINavigationController does not set view properties correctly when pushed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UITabBarControllerDelegate that pushes a new view controller when a certain tab is pressed:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    MyView* myView = [[[MyView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil]autorelease];
        if([self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.title isEqualToString:@"Friends"]){
        NSLog(@"Clicked Friends");
        myView.reloadFriends = TRUE;
        [self.navigationController myView animated:YES]; 
    }
}
```

However, if I change my code to set the tabbar's selected view controller to myView everything works, but I don't get my navigation bar:

```
if([self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.title isEqualToString:@"Friends"]){
        NSLog(@"Clicked Friends");
        myView.reloadFriends = TRUE;
        self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = myView; 
}
```

How can I set the reloadFriends property in MyView and have the navigation bar at the top?

EDIT:
I have also tried the following code w/ no luck:

```
[self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.navigationController pushViewController:myView animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have personally stuck to the style of maintaining my own reference to the navigation controller in the app delegate, and I use the app delegate's reference to the navigation controller to push the new view.

Comment: i don't think i am understanding you. could you post some code to help me understand?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
{
            [(UINavigationController *)viewController pushViewController:myView animated:NO];
}
```